# I want to send my local MySQL database data into the personal server daily at a certain time automatically

Tags: having

I want to send my local MySQL database data into the personal server daily at a certain time automatically.

Comment: what did you try already? people will help you solve errors while you explore for a solution. People won't start writing a solution from scratch for you.

please include some code snippets of what you have, what you tried, and maybe some verbal explanation to describe the problem in more details

hope this helped! welcome to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can write a cron job which will dump the data from the database

You can refer the link  http://www.comentum.com/mysqldump-cron.html for more details.